# Strange function behavior for loop printing out an extra int

Tags: c

I want the function to print out 1 2 3 and then end but it prints out an extra 4 which I don know where it comes from because the for loop finishes at 3

```
#include <stdio.h>

int fun(int var);
//int var = 345;

int i = 0;

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    //printf("%d\n", fun(156));
    for(i = 0; i <= 3; i++){
        fun(i);
    }
    printf("%d \n", i);
    return 0;
}

int fun(int var){
    printf("%d\n", var);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: When the loop exits, i = 4 and is printed before returning from main().

Comment: When the code is cluttered with irrelevant junk (like `int argc, const char * argv[]`), it becomes difficult to _spot_ bugs... Write cleaner code and enjoy fewer problems...

Answer (score 3):

The loop continues while `i <= 3` is true. Therefore it ends when `i <= 3` is false. When `i` is 0, 1, 2, and 3, `i <= 3` is true. `i <= 3` becomes false when `i` is 4. Therefore, after the loop, `i` is 4, and that is what `printf("%d \n", i);` prints.